# How do I save a response from builder.Prompts.confirm() in Microsoft Bot Builder NodeJs

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

How do I get a response value from a user when using builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Did that solve your problem !") in Microsoft Bot Framework (Node Js)

I just want to implement below
 1. if user says "yes", I will say goodbye
 2. If user says "no", I will say please try again

Below is my code snippet

```
if( builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Did that solve your problem buddy !"))
session.send("good by");
else
session.send("Please try again");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to read the [Prompt for user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt) documentation.

Then, in order to get the response, you need to add an additional waterfall step, and then the `response` property.

```
 function (session, args, next) {
      builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Did that solve your problem buddy !");
 },
 function (session, args) {
      if (args.response) {
         session.send("good by");
      else {
         session.send("Please try again");
 }
```